# Intalling mssql-tools and unixodbc-dev on Ubuntu 20

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-20.04

I have tried to install SQL Server command-line tools, but I get the next error

```
sql-tools unixodbc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mssql-tools is already the newest version (17.6.1.1-1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried using `sudo apt install msodbcsql17`  and `sudo apt-get install unixodbc` but get the similar errors with the second command.

Comment: Have you previously [followed the Microsoft instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) to install msodbcsql17?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but now I get the error ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Perhaps this fix for Ubuntu 19.10 is still applicable for 20: [Unmet dependencies block install SQL Server Command Line Tools](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222491)?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the version numbers in your question it appears that you ran the following `curl` command from the Microsoft's [Install tools on Ubuntu 16.04](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu) documentation:

```sh
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    79  100    79    0     0    163      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   163
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial main
```

If you do that on Ubuntu 20.04 then the `apt-get install` will fail with:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As per the documentation you need to change the version number in the repository URL to match your Ubuntu version, so use the following `curl` command on Ubuntu 18.04:

```sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

And the following `curl` command on Ubuntu 20.04:

```sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

After downloading the correct repository reference and performing an `apt-get update` the `apt-get install` command should complete successfully.

Comment: good points but the same error happens even using _20.04/prod.list_

Comment: @WestCoastProjects So what version are Linux are you using? What's the output from `cat /etc/os-release`?

Comment: I'ts ubuntu 20.04 as mentioned. your command simply confirms it

Comment: @WestCoastProjects you might need to ask a new question, including the full output from `apt-get install`, as you may have other broken packages and/or processor architecture issues.

Comment: i had done so just few mins ago: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75925543/unable-to-install-sqlcmd-mssql-tools-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: I added the `cat /etc/os-release` to that question in any case..