# Unable to install Sqlcmd / mssql-tools on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I am following the `Sqlcmd` installation directions from the *microsoft* site here [Install the SQL Server command-line tools sqlcmd and bcp on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?tabs=ubuntu-install%2Credhat-offline&view=sql-server-ver16#ubuntu). The target environment is `ubuntu-20.04` on *Docker*

The following installation does not work

```
sudo apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note that I started manually correcting the missing packages but after a few iterations it led to a non-installable package

```
root@bb72040ed700:/usr/build# apt install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev unixodbc
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
> mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  unixodbc : Depends:
> odbcinst1debian2 (>= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed
> Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed  unixodbc-dev : Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but
> 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Then later:

> libodbc1 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
> odbcinst1debian2 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable

Note: I have already viewed the similar post  [Intalling mssql-tools and unixodbc-dev on Ubuntu 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472806/intalling-mssql-tools-and-unixodbc-dev-on-ubuntu-20) . Since I had already updated the link to *20.04* the answer provided was already incorporated and did not resolve this error.

Per request: here is output of `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Any ideas how to get *Sqlcmd* installed on *ubuntu 20.04* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to install `msodbcsql17` on `ubuntu`: this was the crux of the errors  [Install msodbcsql17 on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1462193/139277)

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```